# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01:19 PM"

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I just try to parse a simple time! Here is my code:

```
   String s = "01:19 PM";
        Date time = null;
        DateFormat  parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        try {
            time = parseFormat.parse(s);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am getting this exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01:19 PM"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Your code works in Java 8.

Comment: No exception with jdk 7 here !!!

Comment: Just to confirm the questioner: I also get the exception using Java 1.7.0_55.

Comment: My Java version is:
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: What is your locale?

Comment: What is your locale? Greek?

Comment: Yes, my locale is Greek!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   String s = "01:19 PM";
   Date time = null;
   DateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
   System.out.println(time = parseFormat.parse(s));
  }
```

ouputs:

```
  Thu Jan 01 13:19:00 KST 1970
```

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your Locale ? I have added the field to the SDF constructor.

Comment: Yes, it's a locale specific problem, see my answer.

Comment: This Answer is **now outdated**, using troublesome old classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the  java.time classes. See modern solution in the [correct Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45287833/642706).

Answer (score 5):

The pattern letter `a` is the Am/pm marker, but it is **locale specific**. Obviously `AM` and `PM` are valid in the English locale, but they are not valid in the Hungarian locale for example.

You get `ParseException` because you have a non-english locale set, and in your locale `PM` is invalid.

```
// This is OK, English locale, "PM" is valid in English
Locale.setDefault(Locale.forLanguageTag("en"));
new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa").parse("01:19 PM");

// This will throw Exception, Hungarian locale, "PM" is invalid in Hungarian
Locale.setDefault(Locale.forLanguageTag("hu"));
new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa").parse("01:19 PM");
```

To get around this problem, the `Locale` can be specified in the constructor:

```
// No matter what is the default locale, this will work:
new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.US).parse("01:19 PM");
```

Answer (score 2):

## `LocalTime`

Modern answer using [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class.

```
LocalTime time = null;
DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter 
    = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
    time = LocalTime.parse(s, parseFormatter);
} catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
    System.out.println(dtpe.getMessage());
}
```

This turns the string from the question, `01:19 PM`, into a `LocalTime` equal to `13:19`.

We still need to provide the locale. Since AM/PM markers are hardly used in practice in other locales than English, I considered `Locale.ENGLISH` a fairly safe bet. Please substitute your own.

Already when this question was asked in 2014, the modern replacement for the old classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` was out, the modern Java date and time API. Today I consider the old classes long outdated and warmly recommend using the modern ones instead. They have generally shown to be remarkably more programmer friendly and convenient to work with.

Just for one simple little thing, if we fail to give a locale on a system with a default locale that doesn’t recognize AM and PM, the modern formatter will give us an exception with the message `Text '01:19 PM' could not be parsed at index 6`. Index 6 is where it says `PM`, so we’re already on our way. Yes, I know there *is* a way to get the index out of the exception thrown by the outdated class, but the majority of programmers were never aware and hence did not use it.

More importantly, the new API offers a class `LocalTime` that gives us what we want and need here: just the time-of-day without the date. This allows us to model our data much more precisely. There are a number of questions on Stack Overflow caused by confusion in turn caused by the fact that a `Date` necessarily includes both date and time when sometimes you want only one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think that instead of `"hh:mm aa"` it should be `"h:mm a"`

Comment: I am getting the same exception! Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you should use this format string: `"h:mm a"`

But also your format string is correct because I'm getting no errors executing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format: `"K:m a"`

Check the docs too: [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
Also, check your locale, your problem seems to be locale-specific.

Comment: Both `K` and `h` are valid, just `K` is in the range of `0..11` and `h` is in the range of `1..12`.

Comment: The same exception! :(