# SimpleDateFormat ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, simpledateformat, parseexception

I want to parse the following date:

```
24 07 2017 3:47:57 AM
```

with the following format:

```
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
df2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
try {
    df2.parse(dateStr + " "+ sunrise);
}catch(ParseException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "24 07 2017 3:47:57 AM"
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that error.

Comment: This code works. It is possible that you changed something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01:19 PM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524284/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-0119-pm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to parse DateTime-string with AM/PM marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618676/unable-to-parse-datetime-string-with-am-pm-marker)

Comment: As an aside, I recommend you drop the outdated classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. The modern Java date and time API, known as `java.time` or JSR-310, is much more programmer friendly, generally much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that your default `Locale` has different symbols for AM/PM. When constructing a date format you should always supply a `Locale` unless you really want to use the system's default `Locale`, for example:

```
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US)
```

Comment: Tested with Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE, it actually throws a ParseException. With my default Locale it works well.

Comment: Yap, that's the issue. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Even if you want the JVM’s default locale, I will prefer you explicitly give `Locale.getDefault()` so the reader too knows you’ve made a conscious choice and you didn’t just forget to choose.