# How to change time format in Java - "am/pm" vs. "AM/PM"

Tags: java, datetime-format, datetimeformatter, timeofday

Tests created previously use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ha");` and returns **"10AM"** (for '`2017-04-09T10:00-06:00[US/Mountain]`').

Under my MacOs and Java ['openjdk version "11.0.12"'] I got **"10am"**

```
"10AM" != "10am"
```

In specification I see "ha" should create "10AM" not "10am"
see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Any advice?

Comment: It depends on the locale used and in the end also on the locale data and hence on the locale data provider. See for example [java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01:19 PM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524284/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-0119-pm)

Comment: Which is the default locale in Java on your Mac? (`System.out.println(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));`)

Answer (score 9):

`DateTimeFormatter` is a Locale-sensitive type i.e. its parsing and formatting depend on the `Locale`. Check [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573) to learn more about it.

If you have an English `Locale`, and you want the output to be always in a single case (i.e. upper case), you can chain the string operation with the formatted string e.g.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
                LocalTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ha", Locale.ENGLISH))
                    .toUpperCase()
        );
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
6AM
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/wvU7EL)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
-Duser.timezone=EDT
-Duser.country=US
-Duser.language=en-US
```

solved issue

Comment: I think that the last one `-Duser.language=en-US`, is decisive here. You may try with it alone. Or keep all three if you like them.

Comment: Don’t use EDT as a time zone. One, it is not, two, three letter time zone abbreviations are ambiguous, more often than not. Three, no place uses Eastern Daylight Time (which I guess you intended) all year. Use for example `America/New_York`. Always use *region/city* format for time zones.