# what method can i use to change format 12 hours time to 24 hour time

Tags: java

I have a task to change format 12 hours time to 24 hours time. What is the method i have to use?
for example:
time like 10.30 AM, 09.12 AM, 09.00 AM
How can I Change to format 24 hours time in java ?

Comment: Basically by applying a different format. What have you tried so far? Can you show us any code attempt?

Comment: I think you ae looking for this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531632/conversion-from-12-hours-time-to-24-hours-time-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69566133/how-to-change-time-format-in-java-am-pm-vs-am-pm

Comment: Also check out [link](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/how-to-convert-12-hour-time-to-24-hour-date-in-java/)

Comment: What type is holding the information in your code? Do you already use a specialzed class like `java.time.LocalTime` for it or do you have `String`s formatted as `"hh:mm a"`?